# Accessing Log4j2 logs within an external .jar

Tags: java, reflection, jar, log4j2

I'm using Java Reflection to run code that's inside a .jar file. However, I should not modify any contents of the file, I have to use the .jar as is. Debugging is tricky (because everything is also obfuscated inside it), so I thought it might be a good idea to have a look at the logger.

I could not find any documentation that is directly relevant for this case, and to be honest I'm a little confused whether or not it is possible.

Here's the **log4j2.xml** that is within the .jar's root:

```
<Configuration status="WARN" packages="net.minecraft,com.mojang">
<Appenders>
    <Console name="SysOut" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="[%d{HH:mm:ss}] [%t/%level]: %msg%n" />
    </Console>
    <Queue name="ServerGuiConsole">
        <PatternLayout pattern="[%d{HH:mm:ss} %level]: %msg%n" />
    </Queue>
    <RollingRandomAccessFile name="File" fileName="logs/latest.log" filePattern="logs/%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz">
        <PatternLayout pattern="[%d{HH:mm:ss}] [%t/%level]: %msg%n" />
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
        </Policies>
    </RollingRandomAccessFile>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Root level="info">
        <filters>
            <MarkerFilter marker="NETWORK_PACKETS" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL" />
        </filters>
        <AppenderRef ref="SysOut"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="ServerGuiConsole"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I looked around, but there does not seem to be a latest.log file, there is also no console output there.

So my question is if getting the log's output is at all possible in any way without altering this xml?

Thank you in advance,

CX